# Pandoc - LaTeX to PDF

Tags: pdf, pandoc

I'm trying to do something like that:

I need to be able to create documents based on template that's written in LaTeX. But when I try using things like: `\huge` or `\begin{center} \end{center}` it doesn't work. Nothing happens (PDF gets generated but everything has the same size and is still aligned to the left)

I've tried editing default.latex file. But I have no idea how to allow the formatting that I need. The only thing that worked for me is putting all the text directly in the default.latex. But that's not a very good solution...

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to LaTeX and pandoc.

Edit (to provide more details):

I convert my .tex file to pdf using command:

```
pandoc --template=mytemplate.latex file.tex -o result.pdf
```

(where I create `mytemplate.latex` using `pandoc -D latex` command)

In order to make it work the way I want I have to put everything from `file.tex` to `mytemplate.latex` and keep `file.tex` empty (except of begin, end of document).

I would like to configure my mytemplate.latex so that I could use things like `\huge`, `\tiny` etc. directly in my `file.tex` and so that `pandoc` could correctly convert `file.tex` to PDF.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you have tagged this question`pandoc`, but there's nothing in the question that mentions how you're using it.  also, without a compilable example showing what you are actually doing, we don't have enough information to help.  (our crystal balls are not functioning very well.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you. I edited my question and provided more information.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `pdflatex` to produce a pdf from a tex file? Pandoc would make sense if the source file were, say, plain text or markdown. But if the source is `tex`, then using pandoc doesn't make sense...

Comment: sorry, still not enough details.  we need to know what `\documentclass` you are using, and packages that might affect the not-working commands.  (or, the comment regarding pdflatex vs. pandoc might hold the answer; i don't use pandoc in this way so don't have useful experience.)

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have used pandoc in the first place. 
Than you all for you help!

Comment: Perhaps it's too late, but I think that you forgot to activate the standalone flag. You could try ```pandoc -s --template=mytemplate.latex file.tex -o result.pdf```.

Comment: Thank you but I've tried it earlier and it didn't help. Just as someone said the answer was to use pdflatex instead of pandoc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.